# JQuery Selector doesn't work for font tag and color attribute, any idea?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I am trying to remove red asterisks on a form, and this is how it is being displayed.

```
<font color=red>*</font>
```

I have more font tags on my code, so I only want to hide those font color = red, and I added this code

```
$('font[color="red"]').hide();
```

works perfect on chorme, but it doesnt work on IE, I am using IE 11 any idea why?

Comment: `<font>` tags are deprecated so they should be replaced in yout HTML anyway.

Comment: Instead of font tags (which are deprecated as Paulie stated) use CSS classes on div or span tags then you can more easily use jquery class selectors to hide and show them.